# OpenCV imshow function is not always working properly

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to read license plate. So I found this tutorial : https://medium.com/programming-fever/license-plate-recognition-using-opencv-python-7611f85cdd6c

And when I run it the `cv2.imshow()` isn't working every time. Sometime I got the image but sometime just the window with a tiny black rectangle in it.  [Here is the little window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/325jf.png)

```
img = cv2.imread('2.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.resize(img, (640,480) )

cv2.imshow('actual', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Just this tiny code is supposed to work everytime if the image exists. But it doesn't.

Does anyone have any clue about this ?

Thanks

Comment: After reading image, checking mage exist or not can be helpful: `if img is None:
    sys.exit("Could not read the image.")` . Use it before `imshow`

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't fix the problem because if the image doesn't exist OpenCV will throw an exception by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to make it work I changed two things :

1. First I had `cv2.namedWindow('actual', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)`
2. And then I updated using : `pip3 install opencv`

And now it's working every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the destroyAllWindows in a loop to close it properly (pressing q):

```
img = cv2.imread('2.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.resize(img, (640,480) )
cv2.imshow('actual', img)
while True:
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer. It seems to work better than the first lines I wrote but it's still not working everytime. It's very strange

Comment: This doesnt answer the question and the suggestion doesnt make any sense